# Excluding pydantic model fields only when returned as part of a FastAPI call

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, starlette

### Context

I have a very complex pydantic model with a lot of nested pydantic models. I would like to ensure certain fields are never returned as part of API calls, but I would like those fields present for internal logic.

### What I tried

I first tried using pydantic's `Field` function to specify the `exclude` flag on the fields I didn't want returned. This worked, however functions in my internal logic had to override this whenever they called `.dict()` by calling `.dict(exclude=None)`.

Instead, I specified a custom flag `return_in_api` on the `Field`, with the goal being to only apply exclusions when FastAPI called `.dict()`.  I tried writing a middleware to call `.dict()` and pass through my own `exclude` property based on which nested fields contained `return_in_api=False`. However FastAPI's middleware was giving me a stream for the response which I didn't want to prematurely resolve.

Instead, I wrote a decorator that called `.dict()` on the return values of my route handlers with the appropriate `exclude` value.

### Problem

One challenge is that whenever new endpoints get added, the person who added them has to remember to include this decorator, otherwise fields leak.

Ideally I would like to apply this decorator to every route, but doing it through middleware seems to break response streaming.

Comment: Really good question. I would just recommend including a bit of super-simplified example code next time. Even code that is _not_ working is good as long as you show what parts of it are not behaving the way they should. Since this is a programming site, most people can grasp an issue much faster when viewing (simplified) code that illustrates it rather than just prose. You could have e.g. given a simple model with one field having `return_in_api=False` and a simple endpoint returning an instance of that model along with the desired output. Your detailed explanation should come after that.

Answer (score 6):

### Excluding fields systematically for all routes

I find it best to work with a concrete albeit super simple example. Let's assume you have the following model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Demo(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: str = Field(return_in_api=False)
```

We want to ensure that `bar` is never returned in a response, both when the `response_model` is explicitly provided as an argument to the route decorator **and** when it is just set as the return annotation for the route handler function. (Assume we do not want to use the built-in `exclude` parameter for our fields for whatever reason.)

The most reliable way that I found is to subclass [`fastapi.routing.APIRoute`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L322) and hook into its `__init__` method. By copying a tiny bit of the parent class' code, we can ensure that we will always get the correct response model. Once we have that, it is just a matter of setting up the route's `response_model_exclude` argument before calling the parent constructor.

Here is what I would suggest:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any

from fastapi.responses import Response
from fastapi.dependencies.utils import get_typed_return_annotation, lenient_issubclass
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute, Default, DefaultPlaceholder


class CustomAPIRoute(APIRoute):
    def __init__(
        self,
        path: str,
        endpoint: Callable[..., Any],
        *,
        response_model: Any = Default(None),
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        # We need this part to ensure we get the response model,
        # even if it is just set as an annotation on the handler function.
        if isinstance(response_model, DefaultPlaceholder):
            return_annotation = get_typed_return_annotation(endpoint)
            if lenient_issubclass(return_annotation, Response):
                response_model = None
            else:
                response_model = return_annotation
        # Find the fields to exclude:
        if response_model is not None:
            kwargs["response_model_exclude"] = {
                name
                for name, field in response_model.__fields__.items()
                if field.field_info.extra.get("return_in_api") is False
            }
        super().__init__(path, endpoint, response_model=response_model, **kwargs)
```

We can now set that custom route class on our router ([documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/)). That way it will be used for *all* its routes:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
# ... import CustomAPIRoute
# ... import Demo

api = FastAPI()
api.router.route_class = CustomAPIRoute


@api.get("/demo1")
async def demo1() -> Demo:
    return Demo(foo="a", bar="b")


@api.get("/demo2", response_model=Demo)
async def demo2() -> dict[str, Any]:
    return {"foo": "x", "bar": "y"}
```

Trying this simple API example out with `uvicorn` and `GET`ting the endpoints `/demo1` and `/demo2` yields the responses `{"foo":"a"}` and `{"foo":"x"}` respectively.

---

### Ensuring schema consistency

It is however worth mentioning that (unless we take additional steps) the `bar` field will **still be part of the schema**. That means for example the auto-generated OpenAPI documentation for both those endpoints **will show** `bar` as a top-level property of the response to expect.

This was not part of your question so I assume you are aware of this and are taking measures to ensure consistency. If not, and for others reading this, you can define a static [`schema_extra`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/#schema-customization) method on the `Config` of your base model to delete those fields that will never be shown "to the outside" before the schema is returned:

```py
from typing import Any
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class CustomBaseModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
            properties = schema.get("properties", {})
            to_delete = set()
            for name, prop in properties.items():
                if prop.get("return_in_api") is False:
                    to_delete.add(name)
            for name in to_delete:
                del properties[name]


class Demo(CustomBaseModel):
    foo: str
    bar: str = Field(return_in_api=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response Daniil. This is super useful, but unfortunately this doesn't entirely solve my problem. I want to exclude those fields even when the model is not the response model. For example, if `Demo` is a child of another model. This code only considers the case where `Demo` is the only thing being returned. I realised this question may have more to do with pydantic than FastAPI, so I have another question up (that you have seen): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030663/excluding-fields-on-a-pydantic-model-when-it-is-the-nested-child-of-another-mode

Comment: @rbhalla You're right. I did not consider the nesting of models. I'm afraid this approach is useless for that. Then the only reasonable way I see is to use the built-in `exclude` capability as you already did, override the `dict` method of the base model and have a convenience method that calls `dict(exclude=None)` for all your other needs. I doubt there is any other (efficient) way to solve this.